# Why is the playsound function not able to play my mp3 file in python

Tags: python, python-playsound

So basically I was trying to create a music playing program that would play music when you asked it to. I was just trying to get the song playing portion to actually work, so I wrote a super simple code to test it out:

```
import playsound
playsound('sample.mp3')
```

This was done in replit, and I added the mp3 file into the files section
[image: as you can see]

when I hit run, it gives me TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `playsound` is the name of the module. I think you need `playsound.playsound`

Comment: or just import the one function: `from playsound import playsound`

Comment: i got this error after doing that: playsound is relying on another python subprocess. Please use `pip install pygobject` if you want playsound to run more efficiently. and also a very long other paragraph i dont want to copy paste into here.

Comment: Running on replit you won't be able to play sound on your computer because the code doesn't actually run on your computer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565340/why-is-the-playsound-function-not-working-on-repl-it

Answer (score 2):

you need to install the PyObjC by writing below command.

if you are using python version 3

> pip3 install PyObjC

if you are using python version 2

> pip install PyObjC

After that you write below code in your terminal

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("path of your audio file/testing_audio_file.mp3")
```

if you are facing any issue regarding path then  use below pattern for (use two forward slash) **Windows**

```
playsound("D:\\path_of_your_audio_file\\testing_audio_file.mp3")
```

Answer (score 1):

By entering this command from the console, your old library will be deleted and this new library will be loaded:

```bash
pip install playsound2
```

You can play your mp3 file with these sample commands in Python:

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound("yourfile.mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, and eventually figured out you need GStreamer. It doesn't say in the error, but if GStreamer in not installed, it does the playing in a different way and throws the error. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libjpeg-dev
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
     gstreamer1.0-tools \
     gstreamer1.0-gl \
     gstreamer1.0-gtk3
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-qt5
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

in your terminal, then try it.

Comment: The question is running code in the cloud on something called Replit. If your answer is about running locally  (Linux?) you should specify this in the answer, as this isn't guaranteed to work on Replit

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. I use an RPi4 with debian...

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
import playsound
```

with...

```
from playsound import playsound
```