# Playing a sound with playsound in WSL gives a long list error

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsl-2, playsound

I try to play a simple sound in my WSL Debian but I cannot fix a long list of errors.
I don't know what to do more...

Searching different advise on the net, I'have installed

```
pip install playsound
apt install libcairo2-dev libgirepository1.0-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0
sudo apt install libxt-dev
pip install pygobject
pip install PyGObject
pip install vext
pip install vext.gi
```

My script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from playsound import playsound
playsound('clock.mp3')
```

errors are :

```
> ./sound.py
playsound is relying on another python subprocess. Please use `pip install pygobject` if you want playsound to run more efficiently.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 261, in <module>
    playsound(argv[1])
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 162, in _playsoundNix
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/nnggu/TabNextCloud/Python/ExxoPython/Journal_Coding/./sound.py", line 6, in <module>
    playsound('clock.mp3')
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 254, in <lambda>
    playsound = lambda sound, block = True: _playsoundAnotherPython('/usr/bin/python3', sound, block, macOS = False)
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 229, in _playsoundAnotherPython
    t.join()
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 218, in join
    raise self.exc
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 211, in run
    self.ret = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py", line 226, in <lambda>
    t = PropogatingThread(target = lambda: check_call([otherPython, playsoundPath, _handlePathOSX(sound) if macOS else sound]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '/home/nguw/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playsound.py', 'clock.mp3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Possible duplicates [why-is-the-playsound-function-not-able-to-play-my-mp3-file-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69200217/why-is-the-playsound-function-not-able-to-play-my-mp3-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wsl sound system till now has issues but you can try installing pulseAudio atleast it worked for me when i was getting choppy audio output. It fixed it but the sound was rather delayed `sudo apt install pulseaudio -y` and `sudo apt install pavucontrol -y`**(optional if you want the gui)**

Answer (score 0):

And by looking at you errors you need to install pygobject and which should solve the missing module error.Use pip to install it

```
pip install pygobject
```